# How can I add validation in Joi that old and new passwords should not be same?

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I am building Apis using NodeJS & ExpressJS and Joi for schema validation.

Here is my Joi validation for my resetUserPinCode controller where I want to check that oldPinCode and newPinCode should not be the same:

```
const resetUserPinCode = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    phoneNumber: Joi.string().required(),
    oldPinCode: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).required(),
    newPinCode: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).required(),
  }),
};
```

I can add check in resetUserPinCode function that oldPinCode and newPinCode are not same but I want to add that in my Joi validation schema. Is there any way I can add that validation in my Joi schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality can be achieved by using `Joi.disallow()` as shown below.

```js
const resetUserPinCode = {
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    phoneNumber: Joi.string().required(),
    oldPinCode: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).required(),
    newPinCode: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).disallow(Joi.ref('oldPinCode')).required(),
  }),
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but how can I add custom message only if oldPinCode and newPinCode do match?